# Issues with IAM Permissions and Authentication For Google Cloud Storage / Speech To Text API. Why do I still not have permissions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-speech-api, google-iam

I receive the following error when I try to run the sample code for Google's Speech To Text API.

Code:

```
from google.cloud import speech_v1p1beta1
from google.cloud.speech_v1p1beta1 import enums


def sample_recognize(storage_uri):
    """
    Performs synchronous speech recognition on an audio file

Args:
  storage_uri URI for audio file in Cloud Storage, e.g. gs://[BUCKET]/[FILE]
"""

client = speech_v1p1beta1.SpeechClient()

# storage_uri = 'gs://cloud-samples-data/speech/brooklyn_bridge.mp3'

# The language of the supplied audio
language_code = "en-US"

# Sample rate in Hertz of the audio data sent
sample_rate_hertz = 44100

# Encoding of audio data sent. This sample sets this explicitly.
# This field is optional for FLAC and WAV audio formats.
encoding = enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.MP3
config = {
    "language_code": language_code,
    "sample_rate_hertz": sample_rate_hertz,
    "encoding": encoding,
}
audio = {"uri": storage_uri}

response = client.recognize(config, audio)
for result in response.results:
    # First alternative is the most probable result
    alternative = result.alternatives[0]
        print(u"Transcript: {}".format(alternative.transcript))
sample_recognize("gs://news2ttestbucket/untitled.mp4")
```

**Error:**

> google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403
>   starting-account-950772mckg4@news2ttest-1581392888505.iam.gserviceaccount.com
>   does not have storage.objects.get access to
>   news2ttestbucket/untitled.mp4.

With regards to the bucket, I've given every conceivable permission to every level of the project and it still refuses to access the file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM84R.png)

Really don't get why it's failing and would appreciate any assistance, thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

In your image, you have shown that you have permissions for:

- Editors of project
- Owners of project
- Viewers of project

If we look in detail at your error message:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied:
403 starting-account-950772mckg4@news2ttest-1581392888505.iam.gserviceaccount.com
   does not have storage.objects.get access to news2ttestbucket/untitled.mp4.
```

We see that the identity that is requesting access to work with the bucket is called:

```
starting-account-950772mckg4@news2ttest-1581392888505.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Assuming that identity is neither a project Editor, Owner or Viewer then none of the permissions apply.  Create a new entry by clicking "Add members" and add permissions for that identity explicitly.